# Java sockets won't connect to server after some time

Tags: java, sockets

I have Java client which connects to my Java server. Java clients are in different networks and are running on MTX-GTW (Embedded Linux).
When I start server and the clients everything works fine, and clients are sending data every 1 minute. But after a day or more, clients will stop sending data one by one. Time varies.
But rest of the program runs fine, since program uses HTTP to communicate with some API and there we are still receiving data.

I checked server debug output and I can't see any errors or exceptions. I tried restarting the server and it also didn't help. My next step will be, to have similar client on my PC, so that I can see debug log, but that can take some time. So would any of you have any idea what could be the problem?

I use Java 7, here I call method to open socket:

```
static private void createHomeCallTimer() 
    {
        new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    log.info("homeCall run");
                    Main main = new Main();
                    String data = "xxxxx";
                    try 
                    {
                        log.info("Start of HOMECALL with data: " + data);
                        new TCPClient().openSocketAndSendData(data);
                        createHomeCallTimer();
                    } catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        log.error("Exception on homeCall: " + e);
                        createHomeCallTimer();
                    }
                }
            }, 
            HOMECALLTIME 
        );
    }
```

And this is client which is called by that method:

```
public class TCPClient
{
    public void openSocketAndSendData(String data) throws IOException
    {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TCPClient.class);
        String ip = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
        int port = 9000;
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        log.info("SOCKET TO IKU SERVER OPENED");
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        log.info("IKU SERVER: " + inFromServer.readLine());
        outToServer.writeBytes(data);
        clientSocket.close();
        log.info("SOCKET CLOSED");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is method `openSocketAndSendData` still called but not sending data or there is no method call?

Comment: I don't have access to those devices debug log, so I don't know. I can just see on the server side that no new sockets are opened.

Comment: Do you know anything about client machines? Maybe your log file gets too big for them, throws exception on `log.info("Start of HOMECALL with data: " + data);`?  You better get your hands on that logs rather than run code on your machine. It might be specific to your client machines...

Comment: It doesn't write it to file, since device has quite small memory. I can remotely connect and restart the program to see the log, but I would have to be remotely connected for a whole day to see what happens.

Comment: Could you try to track memory consumption on the clients? If yes: can you just send this information via the socket to the server? Maybe there is something suspicious ongoing.

Comment: I can remotely connect with Putty and access Linux terminal and with command "TOP" I could probably get memory consumption. I am new to Linux, but I check for memory consumption.

Comment: You don't need to create the home call timer recursively. Just have the executor schedule it at whatever interval you want. You're also in severe danger of leaking sockets here as you have no `finally` blocks. Sockets should be closed in `finally` blocks when you're finished with them.

Comment: @EJP I haven't yet used executor in my program. Would be this correct way to implement it?: http://www.journaldev.com/2340/java-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-example-to-schedule-tasks-after-delay-and-execute-periodically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you said that device has really small memory, then here's my suspect.
I didn't run your code but stripped it a little and speed it up to see what happens.

**Here's code:**

```
public class Main {
    private static final int HOMECALLTIME = 10;

    static private void createHomeCallTimer() {
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                // log.info("homeCall run");
                // Main main = new Main();
                String data = "xxxxx";
                System.out.println(data);

                // log.info("Start of HOMECALL with data: " + data);
                // new TCPClient().openSocketAndSendData(data);
                createHomeCallTimer();

            }
        }, HOMECALLTIME);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createHomeCallTimer();
    }
}
```

And here's output after few minutes:

> Exception in thread "Timer-21424" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable
>   to create new native thread
>
> at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)   at
>   java.util.Timer.(Timer.java:160)    at
>   java.util.Timer.(Timer.java:132)    at
>   pkg.Main.createHomeCallTimer(Main.java:13)    at
>   pkg.Main.access$0(Main.java:12)   at pkg.Main$1.run(Main.java:22)     at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)    at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

I suspect recursive call prevents freeing up memory and you run out of memory on your device. That's just a suspicion, but doesn't quite fit in a comment.

**Here's the same code without recursion, using Timer:**

```
static private void createHomeCallTimer() {
        new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                // log.info("homeCall run");
                // Main main = new Main();
                String data = "xxxxx";
                System.out.println(data);

                // log.info("Start of HOMECALL with data: " + data);
                // new TCPClient().openSocketAndSendData(data);

            }
        }, 0, HOMECALLTIME);
    }
```

Comment: But shouldn't then also rest of the program stop if it would run out of memory? Could you maybe propose how to change method which calls client? So that I would modify program on one of the clients and see if there is difference.

Comment: @Jure you already saw EJP's comment on using scheduled executors. From example you provided I'd change from scheduledThreadPool to singleThreadedExecutor, you don't want to run into problems with multithreading on your client machine.

Comment: @Jure There are different kinds of memory and not every OOM is fatal. For example - if you request a 2GB array to be initialized, you may get an OOM, but after you catch this exception you can go on fine. I imagine in this case you didn't run out of heap space (the typical memory used), but rather that type of memory where new thread stacks are allocated. This would mean that existing threads would continue as per normal, while new threads cannot be created (although the exception might terminate your recursive threads)

Comment: Today I will make modifications to a program that you (zubergu) and @EJP proposed and in few days I will see if they fix the problem and if they do, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I made proposed modifications and after a while it looks OK. So I accepted your answer. Thank you and @EJP for help.